# "None" printed before list elements jinja2

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am building a Flask Web Application that sends a list of dictionaries as a variable to my HTML template. I extract the values in the dictionary and append it to a list using a for loop. I assign variables in my HTML elements to the values in the list. The HTML variables iterate through the elem list using indexing.

```
<div class="container">
     {% set elem = [] %}
     {% for key, value in future[0].items() %}
         {{ elem.append(value) }}
     {% endfor %}
     <div class="future-dayofweek">
         <h3>{{ elem[0] | default('---') }}</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="future-weathericon">
         <i class="wi {{elem[1] | default('wi-cloud')}}"></i>
     </div>
     <p class="future-conditions">{{elem[2] | default('--')}}</p>
     <div class="future-highlow">
         <p class="future-temprange">
             <span class="high">{{elem[3] | default('-')}}</span> | <span class="low">{{elem[4] | default('-')}}</span></p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

My problem is that when the HTML file is rendered I get a "None" value printed before the actual values. There are 5 "None" which is also the length of my list. I changed the way I got the dictionary values by eliminating the "key" expression but that did not fix it.
[Rendered HTML web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFYd7.png).
[Developer Tools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucco7.png)

Answer (score 0):

`{{ elem.append(value) }}` this return `None` and is written inside loop so None is evaluated as many times as length of `future[0].items()`.

You could just use `.values()` if you need all values of dict. `{% set elem = future[0].values() %}`.

More on [lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and [dicts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Tried this but elem is not of type list. It is a dict_values object. I tried `% set elem = list(future[0].values()) %}` but get an _'list' object not callable_ error